# Copy several items background color to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several `li` tags with different background colors.
and I want to when user click on each of `li` tags, get the background color of that specific item and copy it to clipboard.

```
 $('li.col').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
})
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Not an answer, but something to consider. You may be more suitable to use [clipboard.js](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct so far. You can use something like the [`copyToClipboard`](https://30secondsofcode.org/browser#copytoclipboard) method from [30secondsofcode](https://30secondsofcode.org) (a project/website that I maintain) to deal with this. From the website:

> Create a new `<textarea>` element, fill it with the supplied data and add it to the HTML document. Use `Selection.getRangeAt()` to store the selected range (if any). Use `document.execCommand('copy')` to copy to the clipboard. Remove the `<textarea>` element from the HTML document. Finally, use `Selection().addRange()` to recover the original selected range (if any).

```js
const copyToClipboard = str => {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = str;
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  el.style.left = '-9999px';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  const selected =
    document.getSelection().rangeCount > 0 ? document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) : false;
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
  if (selected) {
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    document.getSelection().addRange(selected);
  }
};


$('li.col').click(function() {
  var x = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
  copyToClipboard(x);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="col" style="background:red;">Red</li>
  <li class="col" style="background:green;">Green</li>
  <li class="col" style="background:blue;">Blue</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** I've written an article on Medium that explains this technique a bit more in depth. You can read it [here](https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f).